# Finding all the mooses. Er ... moose? Meese?

Tags: achievements, magicka

I'm unable to find all of the moose throughout the campaign in Magicka. Where are all the moose located? The goal is to get the "King's Quest" achievement.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxenUzZPFiQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Magickapedia](http://www.magickapedia.net) has a list of where you can find each [Moose in each Chapter of the game](http://www.magickapedia.net/index.php?title=Moose_Locations).